# Getting error "sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error"

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to add data to a database from a GUI and using SQLite and getting this error

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\max\Documents\compsci stuff\NEW COMPSCI.py", line 196, in get_items
    C.execute(sql ,vari)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

```
  def get_items(self,*args,**kwargs): #this function gets the items from the entry boxes

        self.carmake= self.carmake_e.get()

        self.carmodel= self.carmodel_e.get()

        self.regi= self.regi_e.get()

        self.colour= self.colour_e.get()

        self.cost= self.cost_e.get()

        self. tcost= self. tcost_e.get()

        self.sellprice= self.sellprice_e.get()

        self.assumedprofit= self.assumedprofit_e.get()

        if self.carmake == " or self.carmodel" == "== self.colour == ":
            print ("WRONG")
            TKInter.messagebox.showinfo("error", "please enter values for car make, model and colour")
        else:
            print ("solid m8")
            sql= "INSERT INTO inventory(car_make,car_model, registration_plate,colour,cost,total_cost,selling_price,assumed_profit) VALUES) (?,?,?,2,?,?,2,?)"
            vari=(self.carmake, self.carmodel,self.regi,self.colour,self.cost,self.tcost,self.sellprice,self.assumedprofit)
            C.execute(sql ,vari)
            C.execute(sql(self.name,self.carmake, self.carmodel, self.regi,self.colour, self.cost,self.tcost,self.sellprice,self.assumedprofit))
            conn.commit()
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("success", "succesfully added to databse!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis in this line

```
sql= "INSERT INTO inventory(car_make,car_model, registration_plate,colour,cost,total_cost,selling_price,assumed_profit) VALUES) (?,?,?,2,?,?,2,?)"
```

`VALUES)` should be `VALUES`.